# Is there a windows clipboard manager that can switch the contents of the clipboard upon pasting?

Tags: windows, windows-8, clipboard

The question is a bit difficult to explain, but what often happens is that I need to copy and replace multiple items quickly. For example, I have two words: "start" and "end". I will highlight "start", copy it, then I will highlight "end" and paste. Then, I'd have to type "end" somewhere else if I want to paste it.

I want to be able to highlight "start", copy it, highlight "end", paste. This paste will paste in "start" and automatically put "end" into the clipboard. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: So to clarify, what you want is a clipboard manager that, when replacing a word via `paste`, puts the replaced word into the clipboard?

Comment: @MarcusChan That's my reading of the question, too, if it helps.  Though the thing replaced need not be a word, of course.

Comment: @MarcusChan That's exactly right--great wording. Do you know of any such solution?

Comment: There are tons and tons of third-party clipboard manager applications for Windows, but I've never tried any of them, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Clipboard contents are controlled by each application: The app asks the clipboard for text (or other content), or puts something it the clipboard. The clipboard doesn't even know what you highlighted until the application tells it. So unfortunately you can't do that in a general way. If you need to do it in Word, look for a Word solution, etc. (Emacs could easily do it, but I doubt that's much help to you)